# remove <br> tag on ckeditor output

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I have integraded a textarea box with ckeditor and each time I press enter on the backend side for a new line it outputs `<br>` on the front end, is there a way to remove `<br>` on the front end as I don't want the html tag output on the front end

I line of code looks like the following

```
echo "<strong>Sites Linked Out To</strong>: " . $row->sites_linked_out_to;
```

is there a way to remove the html `<br>` tag before it gets added to the database or after?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you're literally seeing `<br>` onscreen or that you're getting a line break you don't want?

Comment: sorry yeah I am actually seeing <br> on the screen, I need <br> replacing with a line break

Comment: What are you seeing in the database, `<br>` or `&lt;br&gt;` ? You could grep your code for `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` - odds are you're unnecessarily encoding the string somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but this may help someone..

Use

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($your_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `nl2br()` when you insert the content.

This will replace any `<br>` with a new line `\n`

Note though; If you are actually seeing the tag its probably being url encoded somewhere. If you call `nl2br()` before this encoding takes place it should work.

You could also strip other undesired tags using `strip_tags`. Do this after replacing the new line.

```
define('ALLOWED_TAGS', '<p>,<strong>,<ul>,<li>,<ol>,<em>');
$sContent = strip_tags( nl2br($sContent), ALLOWED_TAGS);
```

Note though, this wont strip out `<a href='#' onclick='DO_SOMETHING_BAD'>click me</a>`

You could look at using a library such as html purifier to sanitise input. Or just ensure you sanitise all output correctly.

See [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)  and [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for more info.

Comment: I thought by having config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; in the ckeditor config.js file, it would remove the <br> tags

Comment: Regardless if that works or not, I wouldn't suggest relying on javascript to do this. What if a user has it disabled and enters HTML or <br> tags themselves?

Answer (score 0):

php strip tags function write in tags secondary parameter, keeping tags, other html tags clean

```
strip_tags($input, '<a><img><div><strong>');
```

more information for strip tags function http://php.net/manual/tr/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: where would I put that line of code, would that go on the php file that is outputting the data from the db

Comment: if $row->sites_linked_out_to variable in ckeditor output string, then `echo "<strong>Sites Linked Out To</strong>: " . strip_tags($row->sites_linked_out_to, '<a><img><div><strong>');`

Comment: I tried your code but is still outoputting <br> tag when I press enter in the ckeditor in the textarea on the backend

Comment: Before db insert filtered value, but i don't know your insert codes.

Comment: my insert code looks like this-> $sites_linked_out_to = htmlentities($_POST['sites_linked_out_to'], ENT_QUOTES); and // insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT websites (sites_linked_out_to) VALUES (?,)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sites_linked_out_to);

Comment: edit line this way can work.
`$sites_linked_out_to = strip_tags($_POST['sites_linked_out_to'], '<a><img><div><strong>');`

Comment: I tried that and has stripped out the <br> tags but when I press enter within the ckeditor on the backend, the front end is not adding a new line now